# Error Spring after changing Eclipse Luna to Eclipse 2023-09 version 'Unable to build hbm.xml JAXBContext' due to 'Implementation of JAXB-API not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

[image]

Workspace works properly in LUNA but Eclipse 2023-12,2022-09 or any other it gives the above

```
error.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [data-access.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to build hbm.xml JAXBContext."
```

The root cause points to a configuration problem, specifically the absence of the JAXB-API implementation. Further investigation reveals a ClassNotFoundException for `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory`, indicating a missing dependency. This issue impacts the application's functionality as it fails to initialize the entity manager factory, hindering database access and persistence operations. Resolving this problem involves identifying and resolving the missing JAXB dependency, ensuring it is correctly configured within the project's build path or Maven dependencies. Addressing this issue will restore the application's functionality, enabling seamless operation within the Spring Framework environment post-Eclipse version update